# Psplash on Raspberry Pi blinks on boot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, splash-screen, yocto, raspberry-pi4

I have Yocto image for my Raspberry Pi 4B with HDMI screen connected. I'm using psplash to display splash screen on boot. But splash screen blinks twice on each boot. There is 10 seconds black screen on start, then image shows up for 3-4 seconds, then 3-4 seconds black screen and then image shows again. I wasn't able to investigate, what causes the middle black screen. There are no relevant logs in journalctl, nothing seems relevant in dmesg... Can you give me some ideas, what could cause this behaviour?
Thank you,
Michal

Comment: Some other application takes over the framebuffer for some reason. When it quits, psplash gets it back.

Comment: @skandigraun, I have checked systemd-analyze plot output an there shouldn't be any other service related with display. Is there some way, how to log display access from applications?

Comment: Not that I know of, but as a quick and dirty debug method, you could try disabling the services one by one from autostarting, and reboot to see if anything changes.